# Error al restaurar archivo .Bak de SQL Server 2014, envia error de "is terminating abnormally"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, zip

Tengo un desarrollo en visual studio que realiza respaldos de la base de datos de un servidor SQL Server 2014 Standar Edition, después de realizar los respaldos hay una rutina para poder comprimirlos y dejarlos como archivos .Gz:

Los respaldos se hacen con la siguiente linea:

> *BACKUP DATABASE [NombreBase] TO DISK = N'D:\' WITH NOFORMAT, CHECKSUM, NOINIT, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10*

y la compresion con el siguiente codigo:

Public Sub Comprime_Archivo(ByVal archivoEntrada As String, ByVal archivoSalida As String)

```
    Try
        Using sourceFile As FileStream = File.OpenRead(archivoEntrada)
            Using destFile As FileStream = File.Create(archivoSalida)
                Using compStream As GZipStream = New GZipStream(destFile, CompressionMode.Compress)
                    Dim data(sourceFile.Length) As Byte
                    sourceFile.Read(data, 0, data.Length)
                    compStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
                    compStream.Close()
                End Using
                destFile.Close()
            End Using
            sourceFile.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        DtsBit.T_ErrorS = Mid(ex.Message, 1, 500)
        Call FuncBit.Error_Trabajo_Bitacora(DtsBit)

        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub
```

pero al momento que descomprimo los respaldos ya sea con 7zip, winzip, winrar o con el siguiente codigo:

Public Sub Comprime_Archivo(ByVal archivoEntrada As String, ByVal archivoSalida As String)

```
    Try
        Using sourceFile As FileStream = File.OpenRead(archivoEntrada)
            Using destFile As FileStream = File.Create(archivoSalida)
                Using compStream As GZipStream = New GZipStream(sourceFile, CompressionMode.Decompress)
                    Dim data As Integer

                    data = compStream.ReadByte()

                    While (data <> -1)
                        destFile.WriteByte(CByte(data))

                        data = compStream.ReadByte()
                    End While

                End Using

            End Using

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub
```

no puedo restaurarlos en el servidor SQL ya que manda el error de "is terminating abnormally", lo que detecte es que si en la linea que realiza el respaldo omito el atributo

> COMPRESSION

si puedo descomprimir los respaldos y restaurarlos sin problema.

¿alguien sabe como puedo rescatar los respaldos que ya tenia para que pueda restaurarlos?